# Offline Data Editing on Versioned Data?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, versioning

I have registered my layer as "*Registered as  versioned*" with the "*Register the selected objects with the option to move edits to base*".

I can publish the the data the feature server with "Sync" features on.

Data can be used online, but when trying to "download the map" for "offline" use.

**The application logs says :**

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=400 "Failed to create replica." UserInfo={NSURL=http://52.28.226.146/arcgis/rest/services/yyy/yyyy/FeatureServer/jobs/j57ac7b5825c446e0a9e29de2faee7700?f=json&token=QE3SFRWbxkrxEbwfgxz3w-54a8amIH1Rv7rcIAnrfGv1mM5C8pbi1QVr0rB_KjFC, responseJSON={
    error =     {
        code = 400;
        description = "Failed to create replica.";
    };
    lastUpdatedTime = 1458648838000;
    replicaName = "";
    resultUrl = "";
    status = Failed;
    submissionTime = 1458648835000;
}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to create replica.}
```

And when checked "Arcgis server Manager" logs **2 error occurs** :

**Error 1**

> Error executing tool.:
>   ErrorMsg@SyncGPService:{"code":400,"description":"Failed to create
>   replica."} Failed to execute (Create Feature Service Replica).

**Error 2**

> Error: An error occurred while adding an entry to the
>   FEATUREDATASET_CLASSES or the FEATURECLASSES table. [Read only data or
>   unversioned data cannot be replicated. Data versioned with the option
>   to move edits to base cannot be replicated. GlobalIDs are required for
>   two way and one way replica data. Creating one way replica using
>   archiving requires archiving the replicated parent data.].

**The achivement goal is :**

Publish a feature server to use on mobile for online/offline editing with versioned data and all changes and updates shown on service immediately.

**What i have already tried :**

- Read the prepare offline map and feature documentation and made sure
  that i had Global ID
- When i do not use "Register the selected objects
  with the option to move edits to base" for data versioning option.
  Data is not displaying on the server when sync in offline mods even if i stop the service and tried to compress the data to DB.

**Why we need versioning :**

To be able to change and edit on Arcmap and webservices for multiple users.

***Using : Arcgis 10.3***

Comment: +1 because I wish all questions included this much detail :)

Comment: "immediately" is tough, but is it necessary?  If you're offline then sync it back does an extra 5 minutes matter?  we have our offline versions post every 5 minutes so any syncs are available in default version within 5 minutes.  Online edits are instant (they don't need to be posted)